# Why dpToPixel should not be used to set layout dimensions?

Tags: android, android-layout

Why in javadocs for `dpToPixel` (declared [here](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/master/leakcanary-android/src/main/java/com/squareup/leakcanary/internal/LeakCanaryUi.java#L44)) is stated that it shouldn't be used to set layout dimensions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't use pixels to define layout dimensions. Using *density independent pixels* ensures proper layout sizes across a variety of devices. Meaning said layout will have roughly the same visual size on a 4" phone and a 7" tablet. (Which is completely unrelated to the problem at hand :) )

That being said the actual layout sizes (e.g. `LayoutParams` class) are in fact using *whole* pixels to define the resulting size. It is viable to use the `dpToPixels` method in this way:

```
float px = dpToPixels(16, getResources()); // 16 dp to pixels precise
int pxOffset = (int) px; // 16dp rounded down to whole pixels
int pxSize = (int) (0.5f + px); // 16dp rounded up to whole pixels
```

Now you can use these values in layouts, **`pxOffset` for padding, margin etc. (can be zero) and `pxSize` for width and height (ensures at least 1px size unless zero)**. The same calculation is done when using methods `int Resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(int)` and `int Resources.getDimensionPixelSize(int)` which are suitable for use with layouts and `float Resources.getDimension(int)` which is suitable for drawing precisely.

#### EDIT

Elevation uses `float` values so using the precise dimension is completely fine.

TranslationX, translationY or translationZ are defined using `float` values. These and many more view properties are used for animation so it makes sense to use smooth values. If set by hand use whole integers for predictable behavior.